# Rviz | tf | scan - (No transform to fixed base)

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, frames, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I'm facing issues with scan data visualization on rviz. The following pictures show the problem:

[image: image description]

**image 1**

---

[image: image description]

**image 2**

---

As we can see from image 1, the transformation between the **laser** and **base_link** frames is defined, nevertheless **rviz** does not find this transformation and so can not display the scan data. To be more precisely, the reported message is:

> Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]

and in sequece

> For frame [laser]: No transform to fixed frame [base_link]. Tf error: [Lookup would require extrapolation to the future. Requested **time 1469464365.119867794** but the latest data is at time **1469463838.127784645**, when looking up transform from frame [laser] to frame [base_link]]

Well, I know that a lot of problems of visualizing data in rviz is related with **timestemp** and I a read a bunch of topic theads here, in the forum, but I do not realize how to solve this issue.

Here goes additional information and pictures:

[image: image description]

The command:

> **rosrun** tf tf_echo laser base_link

and

> **rosrun** tf tf_echo base_link laser

runs without problem. But the command:

> **rosrun** tf tf_monitor laser base_link

return a strange message that is:

> RESULTS: for laser to base_link Chain is: odom -> base_link -> base_link ->
> base_link -> base_link -> base_link -> base_link -> base_link -> base_link ->

> base_link Net delay     avg =
> 0.350788: max = 0.548574
>
> Frames: Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309 Frame: base_link published by
> unknown_publisher Average Delay:
> 0.400253 Max Delay: 0.400309
>
> All Broadcasters: Node:
> unknown_publisher 256.402 Hz, Average
> Delay: 0.400246 Max Delay: 0.40031

as we can see, there is a strange loop behavior in the **Chain** (first line)

The using multiple machines, so maybe there is a problem with synchronization.

Any clue to where should I start or to what should I do to resolve this???

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240336/rviz-%7C-tf-%7C-scan---(no-transform-to-fixed-base)/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found de origem of the problem. It was caused, as I suspect, by the time difference between the machines that were running the roscore and the tf transformation. I only synchronized them and I got the publication of the scan data stream on rviz.

Although I do no used, I think that I good solution is presented [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11570/ros-time-across-machines/).

For me, just as a first workaround, I used the command:

```
sudo ntpdate MACHINE_IP
```

where the **MACHINE_IP** variable contains the IP of the machine that used as reference to synchronize the other machines. (The command is executed in the machine that needs to be synchronized)

---

Originally posted by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) with karma: 236 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1